# Disable the workbox log in Vaadin Hilla

Tags: vaadin, hilla

Because there are so many workbox log entries, I would like to disable them. Hilla generate the sw.js file, so I don't know how and where to do that.

I have to write 220 chars, but I don't what to write anymore. Sry for that line.